# How to use different workspaces on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: workspaces

I heard something about having multiple work spaces on Ubuntu 14.04 and was curious about it.

Comment: Just enable workspace option in Appearance->Behaviour

Comment: @Seth: This should not be a duplicate question. How to USE workspaces is not the same question as how to TURN ON workspaces.

Answer (score 61):

Press `Windows Key` -> Type `appearance`

[image]

Click `Behaviour` tab

[image]

On Launcher click this icon

[image]

This is workspace. Workspaces are multiple desktop screens to work effeciently.

Go to `Keyboard` from `System settings` & `Navigation` & set your shortcuts for moving betweeen workspaces & handling softwares.